# What encoding or data type can be used to get alphanumeric string in elixir?

Tags: scala, elixir, bitcoin

My goal is to guess alphanumeric strings for Bitcoin mining to match leading zeros. For this, I have to increment the encoded string and check whether the string produces the expected [Nonce](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Nonce).

For example in scala, we can use base36 binary to text encoding:- 
BigInt(someAlphaNumString, 36) and increment it by adding BigInt(1, 36) to our string.

What is the better way to do same in elixir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integers in Elixir are arbitrary precision integers, so there's no need for any special BigInt data type. You can convert a base-36 string to and from integer using `String.to_integer/2` and `Integer.to_string/2` like this:

```
iex(1)> a = String.to_integer("DOGBERT", 36)
29776764809
iex(2)> b = a + 1
29776764810
iex(3)> Integer.to_string(b, 36)
"DOGBERU"
```